# Influences on Woody Allen’s “Wonder Wheel”

Tags: analysis, wonder-wheel

I recently watched Woody Allen’s latest movie, [Wonder Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Wheel_(film)). I loved the movie and  my first impression was a possible  influence by [Tennessee Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennessee_Williams)'s works, especially regarding  the main character Ginny.

Does anyone agree on this? Did other users notice Tennessee Williams' style in depicting the main character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not seen the film, but I have read a few reviews that believe, **YES**, Woody Allen is continiously obsessed with ***A Street Car Named Desire***...

**Here are three reviews that observe Tennesee Williams influences:**

> **Woody Allen seems increasingly haunted by the Tennessee Williams play
>   “A Streetcar Named Desire.”** The basic situation of that Williams
>   classic was reused for Allen’s “Blue Jasmine,” which won Cate
>   Blanchett an Oscar, and it is repurposed again (but somewhat
>   transposed) for “Wonder Wheel,” a film about a frustrated woman in
>   1950s Coney Island named Ginny (Kate Winslet)...
>
> Blanchett got her Oscar for “Blue Jasmine” because Allen gave her the
>   opportunity to break down and mentally unravel in a colorfully
>   histrionic fashion in practically every scene. He has given Winslet a
>   similar assignment and opportunity here, and she enters
>   whole-heartedly into many demanding long takes where Ginny reveals her
>   dashed hopes and her strident needs. This is a weak, sometimes deluded
>   woman at the end of her tether who nearly always has a headache, and
>   her desperation when it comes to holding on to Mickey’s affections
>   starts to become very overbearing as the film goes on...
>   https://www.thewrap.com/wonder-wheel-review-woody-allen-kate-winslet-justin-timberlake/

---

> **If you watch a Woody Allen movie one of the first things that you can
>   catch early on is how much the man LOOOOOOVES Tennessee Williams for a
>   lot of his films have the narrative elements of a Williams play.**  This
>   man is trying so hard to be Tennessee Williams for every single movie
>   that has to deal with an affair; this ultimately becomes ‘A Streetcar
>   Named Desire’ like every single film Allen made the last ten years.
>   What makes this film egregious on top of the familiar narrative that
>   we've seen a million times is the additional nonessential layers added
>   so that it won’t be viewed as a ‘Streetcar’ knockoff.
>   http://www.rendyreviews.com/movies//wonder-wheel-review

---

> Woody Allen's last feature, Café Society, was an amiably forgettable
>   assembly of recycled nostalgia, redeemed by a luminous performance
>   from Kristen Stewart. His new film, Wonder Wheel, rummages in the more
>   recent archives, repackaging elements of one of the prolific
>   writer-director's most acclaimed late-period works, Blue Jasmine.
>   While theatrical references are batted about to Chekhov, Shakespeare,
>   O'Neill and the Greeks, **this visually luscious, 1950s-set melodrama is
>   mostly ersatz Tennessee Williams, this time around with Kate Winslet
>   as the tragic Blanche DuBois stand-in.** Her boldly unfettered
>   performance keeps you watching, even if underlying sourness, tonal
>   uncertainty and a key casting misstep diminish the effectiveness of
>   this Amazon Studios release, likely cramping its box office. https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/review/wonder-wheel-review-nyff-2017-1047865

Comment: As a fan of other WA films, I would agree that many of them are Williams-esque and so, I coud easily believe in the influence in this one too.

Comment: and who can forget Sleeper

Comment: Yes, Blue Jasmine’s character is certainly also along that line , but it didn’t cross my mind when I watched the movie. Probably the ‘50s scenery of Wonder Wheel  is closer to Tennessee Williams’s atmospheres.

Comment: I think there are also other influences and probably "wooden allen tropes" too, so it's just a matter of how one is looking at it, but I agree with your comments @user159691